# KitKat SMS limit and override limit pre-KitKat

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

What is the SMS/hour limit for KitKat? Previously it was [30 per 30 minutes](https://plus.google.com/+AlSutton/posts/6XP2HcvPkvX).

Also is it possible to override that limit pre-KitKat (or in KitKat too if it has a limit) without Root access? SMS apps such as [Chomp SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms) and Textra SMS seem to allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMS limit is 30 text messages ever minute in KitKat (4.4) and so far in the 5L preview.

To find the most up to date values go to `com.android.internal.telephony.SmsUsageMonitor` for the latest version of Android and check the values `DEFAULT_SMS_CHECK_PERIOD` & `DEFAULT_SMS_MAX_COUNT`.

http://grepcode.com/search?query=SmsUsageMonitor

Currently in Android 4.4:

```
Default checking period for SMS sent without user permission.
71 
72     private static final int DEFAULT_SMS_CHECK_PERIOD = 60000;      // 1 minute
73 

Default number of SMS sent in checking period without user permission.
74 
75     private static final int DEFAULT_SMS_MAX_COUNT = 30;
```

Comment: ok but what to do with these constants? How to remove these limits?

Comment: Well you could develop your app around them. As far as I know, and I'm pretty certain about this, you can't change these unless the device is rooted.